# Rdlc hide column

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I have a rdlc report which is like below. I want to set visible false AraciFirmaField if AraciFirma is null from Dataset1. Is it possible ? How can i do ?

```
<DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="AraciFirma">
          <DataField>AraciFirma</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="AliciFirma">
          <DataField>AliciFirma</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
..........
```

Comment: Visibility of what? Is this in a table? If so are all the AliciFirma fields going to be null if one is?

Answer (score 0):

In `Visibility.Hidden` property of AraciFirmaField you have to specify if the object must be hide or not. So you can use:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AraciFirma.Value), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Select Column in tablix
- Go to column visibility option
- select show or hide column based on expression.